# ADF Error code 2011: Required property 'connectionString' is not provided in connection properties

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-adf, linked-service

I am trying to connect to snowflake using linked service and copy data from adls to SF using adf pipeline. I created the linked service and tested the connection. It works fine. Even the debug over the pipeline works fine. althogh when I manually try to trigger the pipeline I get "Required property 'connectionString' is not provided in connection properties"

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a configuration issue and this behavior is noticed when the linked service is configured to use parameters (linked service parameterization), or a key vault is used, and if the connection string value isn't passed to the linked serviced during runtime.

Since it is working in debug mode, I would recommend publishing your linked service and in case if it is parameterized or using AKV, then please make sure that the connection string value is being passed and evaluated at runtime.